# DDD in PHP -> DomainEventPublisher -> Where to use the subscribe method?

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, domain-events

The flow:

CreateNewTaskRequest -> CreateNewTaskService -> Task::writeFromNew() -> NewTaskWasCreated(domain event) -> DomainEventPublisher calls handle on subscribers.

Following the flow above, I'm wondering where do you add subscribers for domain events?

I'm currently reading the book [DDD in PHP](https://leanpub.com/ddd-in-php/), but I'm unable to grasp where this should be done?

This is the code I have but feels wrong to me

```
public static function writeNewFrom($title)
    {
        $taskId = new TaskId(1);
        $task = new static($taskId, new TaskTitle($title));

        DomainEventPublisher::instance()->subscribe(new MyEventSubscriber());

        $task->recordApplyAndPublishThat(
            new TaskWasCreated($taskId, new TaskTitle($title))
        );

        return $task;
    }
```

Task extends Aggregate root:

```
class AggregateRoot
{
    private $recordedEvents = [];

    protected function recordApplyAndPublishThat(DomainEvent $domainEvent)
    {
        $this->recordThat($domainEvent);
        $this->applyThat($domainEvent);
        $this->publishThat($domainEvent);
    }

    protected function recordThat(DomainEvent $domainEvent)
    {
        $this->recordedEvents[] = $domainEvent;
    }

    protected function applyThat(DomainEvent $domainEvent)
    {
        $modifier = 'apply' . $this->getClassName($domainEvent);
        $this->$modifier($domainEvent);
    }

    protected function publishThat(DomainEvent $domainEvent)
    {
        DomainEventPublisher::instance()->publish($domainEvent);
    }

    private function getClassName($class)
    {
        $class = get_class($class);
        $class = explode('\\', $class);
        $class = end($class);

        return $class;
    }

    public function recordedEvents()
    {
        return $this->recordedEvents;
    }

    public function clearEvents()
    {
        $this->recordedEvents = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't couple your aggregates to a specific publisher. A much better alternative is to publish recorded events from the event store or the repository. Also, your DomainEventPublisher class is not thread-safe. You should have thread-local members in there or whatever is the equivalent in PHP. Finally, it is not the aggregates that subscribes to domain events. ARs publish events and they do not care who listens. You can add subscribers anywhere else, the application layer during bootstrap, in a specific command handler, in infrastructure if somehow that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

The [DomainEventPublisher](https://github.com/dddinphp/ddd/blob/b540450634e2af0dd7f27c0c1ad5c3a93fbb63a6/src/Domain/DomainEventPublisher.php) class is a singleton, and you can add a subscriber with

```
DomainEventPublisher::instance()->subscribe(new YourSubscriber());
```

where `YourSubscriber` implements [`DomainEventSubscriber`](https://github.com/dddinphp/ddd/blob/b540450634e2af0dd7f27c0c1ad5c3a93fbb63a6/src/Domain/DomainEventSubscriber.php).

Comment: Yes, but when should you add a subscriber in the the flow from above? Where do you make that call? in the writeFromNew method just before you publish the domain event?

Comment: you add it before the controllers are even executed.

Comment: So for instance, my bootstrapper file calls a file where all the subscribers for all domain events are added?

Comment: @MennoHorde sure, why not? Remember that your domain objects don't know who subscribe to their events

Comment: Understood thnx! My question is answered :)